# Relative indentation using CSS

Tags: html, css, webkit, pretty-print

I'm trying to port a pretty-printer for a programming language to HTML. An example output from the pretty printer would be this:

```
P : Prop
⊢ (λ (x y : ℕ), 
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
      16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 21, 22, 23, 24] = [4, 5, 6]) = λ (x y : ℕ), 3 = 3
```

From the pretty printer, we get to know how far things must be indented, but also they may not be indented, if they fit in a single line.

The rule is, that whenever you are nested, you you have to indent however much the parent already indented but also a little bit more.

In this example, the `λ` indents by 4 characters and the list `[...]` indents by 1. That's why 1 and 16 are aligned.

And I'm trying to make a CSS style sheet that can do this kind of thing.

So far, the best I could find was making an element with `display: inline-block; text-indent: -4ch; padding-left: 4ch;`.

This more or less works, but it introduces line breaks where they wouldn't be needed or wanted.

What I'm looking for is something like `display: inline` that also respects `text-indent`.

Is there some way to do this in CSS, or possibly what would be a reasonable way of doing this? We would like the browser to introduce line breaks as needed, respecting where they are allowed and where not.

Current sample: [uploaded to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xbzhL60m/)

Comment: Unclear what's the problem with `display: inline-block`. Perhaps a reproducing fiddle would help us help.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I uploaded my repro to jsfiddle. The problem becomes apparent when you resize.

Comment: In your above example, why would the line break after `15`?

Comment: Ok, so this is a hand-constructed example, but nevertheless, there are certain places where you have non-breaking spaces. So it could be, that in fact it would line break after, say, 18. Yet, breaking inside of the brackets may not be allowed.